# Apache Camel reference property files with and without OSGI

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf

I understand that if you deploy your Camel project to an OSGI environment like Karaf you can simply write:

```
<cm:property-placeholder id="INT001_********_Properties" persistent-id="INT001_SelfServiceMachine" />

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
        id="INT001_SelfServiceMachine" useMDCLogging="true">
        <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="blueprint:INT001_*********_Properties"/>
```

And this works when the project is deployed to Karaf and the property file is located there in the etc folder.

But how can you configure it when Karaf is not available?

I used this bean before:

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent"> 
    <property name="location" value="classpath:some.properties" 
    /> </bean>
```

But is there a single way to refer to property files regardless of when you are in Karaf or when you are in your e.g. Eclipse environment and your property file is in your /src/resources folder and the bean above works? For instance, when you use Jenkins and and want to run tests and build the bundle, you may not have Karaf available.

Thanks for any input on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe implement your own `PropertiesResolver` which know how to resolve your properties according to the runtime environment. If OSGi is detected, then it can use ConfigurationAdmin, else it can use a static properties file.

Personally, I use something more simple thanks to Spring DM: my beans/configurations are dispatched in multiples files, and all the configuration related to OSGi is regrouped in one file. In Karaf, Spring DM load all XML in META-INF/spring. Outside of Karaf, I filter the XML to exclude the OSGi configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a blueprint noosgi bundle around, that one can be used to have the blueprint capabilities outside of the osgi container. With this you're able to stick to your blueprint xml, though you need to change from configuration admin service for property lookup to native blueprint property replacement.